# ¿Como disparar un pop-up al hacer scroll en mi pagina con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5, popup

Quiero que se disparé un pop-up al hacer scroll hacia abajo en mi pagina.

Realicé este código con JavaScript el problema esta que cada vez que hago scroll aparece.. Como hago para que aparezca una vez y pueda seguir haciendo scroll sin que se disparé ?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
```

});

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¡Hola!

Puedes crear una variable que te guarde el número de veces que ha hecho scroll, y que al hacerlo, la función te compruebe si es la primera vez. Entonces, si es el caso, te muestra el mensaje; y si no, no te hace nada. Algo como esto:

```
var cantScroll = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if(cantScroll == 0){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        cantScroll++;
    }
});
```

¡Espero haber sido de ayuda!

¡Un saludo!

Comment: Hola gracias!! Funciona bien

Comment: Genial @AndersonSosa!! Me alegro mucho!! Si te parece que es la respuesta a tu pregunta, por favor, márcala como correcta haciendo click en el check verde de la parte izquierda de la respuesta. Así a otros también les sirve de ayuda!! Saludos!! ;D

Answer (score 1):

Poniendo una variable q controle el estado del popup

```
Let popupState = false;
$(window).scroll(function(){
 If( popupState == false){
$('#myModal').modal('show');
popupState = true;
}else return;
});
```